# Express failing to look up view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to create a SPA app, but when i start my application it does an infinte loop leading to a crash. I am using ExpressJS 4.3.0

App architecture:

> public
>
> --partials
>
> ----index.jade
>
> server.js

My express code:

```
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render('partials/index');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('partials/index');
});
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/partials/' + req.params.name);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
```

If i use

```
res.render('/partials/index');
```

i recieve a message:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/partials/index" in views directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of view lookup function in express [view lookup](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js#L59)

```
if (!utils.isAbsolute(path)) path = join(this.root, path);
```

which makes it assume '/partial/index' is already an absolute path and didnt prefix with root path.

Also move the

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   res.render('partials/index');
});
```

to end else it will always serve the index view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you shouldn't have a preceding `/` in your view path in `render()`. Just use `'partials/' + req.params.name`.

On a related note, are you sure you want your actual view files to be public? Usually they are stored outside of the public static directory (e.g. `./public` contains static assets and `./partials` contains views). Also that way you don't have to keep prefixing view paths with `partials/`.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem with crashing. I'have had 3 different results: Express doesn't find the views/finds the views, but does an infinite loop and crashes/finds the views, but fails to load static files.As for the architecture i will probably move all of those files in a server directory. Thanks for that tip!